# How to create a ClickOnce installer that runs silently and requires no user interaction?

Tags: clickonce

Ideally no window would pop up at all when setup.exe is invoked, but it would be nice to save the user from having to click "OK" on installing pre-requisites and other options. Is that even possible with [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce)?

Comment: The scenario I am thinking of involves running setup.exe on a local hard drive from the command line, so it is a bit different from a website hosting something.

Comment: See [Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Installer for a ClickOnce Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997001%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) - "Any ClickOnce application **based on an .exe file** can be silently installed and updated by a custom installer"

Answer (score 3):

**Additional Files**

Additional components (files and DLL files) can be added automatically as part of the download in the property pages of your project 'Publish' > 'Application Files...'.

**Prerequisties**

As for prerequisties, this will require the users permission (unless you code this to perform a silent install when your application starts - not recommended and nasty solution). At work I got Infrastructure to roll out prerequisites such as .NET 3.5/4.0.

**Silent ClickOnce install**

To create a silent ClickOnce installer, set the MinimumRequiredVersion element in your [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation)/[Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) project file to same version as ApplicationVersion.

```
<PropertyGroup>
<Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
<Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x86</Platform>
...
<MinimumRequiredVersion>1.0.22.1</MinimumRequiredVersion>
<ApplicationVersion>1.0.22.1</ApplicationVersion>
...
</PropertyGroup>
```

If these version numbers are the same, the user will not be prompted with a dialog to update.

At work, I have automated this using a custom build number from [TFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server) to set the version MinimumRequiredVersion and ApplicationVersion in the project file.